# Javascript convert 2D array to array of pairs

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm trying to implement the Highcharts drilldown pie chart and I'm working on the drilldown array in the chart object.

In my AJAX JSON I have an array of arrays, which I need to transform into an array of pairs for Highcharts to pick it up.

What I have:

```
data: Array[1]
  Array[2]
   "California"
   21.56
id: "US"
name: "US",
data: Array[1]
 Array[2]
   "New York"
   41.3
id: "US"
name: "US"
```

I need it to look something like:

```
name: 'US',
id: 'US',
data: [
    ['California', 21.56],
    ['New York', 41.3],
    ...
]
```

The code I'm using that gives me this:

```
$.each(data[1].data, function(key, val){
  drilldown.series.push({name: val['name'], id: val['name'], data: [ val['data'] ] }) ;// this doesn't work
  drilldown.series.push({name: val['name'], id: val['name'], data: [ val['data'][0], val['data'][1] ] }) ;// this works
});
```

The JSON coming from my server looks like this:

```
"data":[
  {
    "name":"US",
    "id":"US",
    "data":[
      [
        "California", 21.56
      ],
      [
        "Florida", 7.98
      ],
      [
        "Texas", 7.39
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It looks like the input and output you posted are the same. That is to say Array[2] === ['v11.0', 24.13].

Comment: @RobertCorey then how come I have to specify elements individually before highcharts sees the data ? If I hard code `val['data'][0]` it works

Comment: Those objects in `$.each` don't match anything in expected output.

Comment: @charlietfl there's more to that object than the `data` array, but that's the one I'm having problems with

Comment: Provide better input sample . We have no idea what the mapping from input to the data array is

Comment: Isn't this the problem with format? Change: `drilldown.series.push({name: val['name'], id: val['name'], data: [ val['data'] ] })` to `drilldown.series.push({name: val['name'], id: val['name'], data: val['data'] })`

Comment: @PawełFus ugh so stupid, thanks ! can you make it an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the problem with format. Change:

```
drilldown.series.push({name: val['name'], id: val['name'], data: [ val['data'] ] })
```

to:

```
drilldown.series.push({name: val['name'], id: val['name'], data: val['data'] })
```